# Alert firing on ready but action not working

Tags: jquery

On page load I want a div to be hidden. I attached an alert that is appearing but its not hiding the div.

Code:

```
$(function () {
   alert('test');
   $('#hide').hide();
});


<div id="hide">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Diggs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [Seems to work as far as I can see](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHvTs/). Have you got more than one element with the id `hide`?

Comment: Have you considered changing the `alert` to: `alert($('#hide').length);` to show whether the selector's finding anything? If the `length` is greater than 1 your document is invalid, and if it's less than 1 it's not finding anything. Have you checked the console for errors? (Firebug, for Firefox, Web Inspector for Chrome/Chromium and Safari, Dragonfly for Opera...)

Comment: This works fine for me on chrome.  Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/unhBv/

Comment: is jQuery loading properly? Are you running this code after you've loaded the jQuery library?

Comment: I know this code usually works. I have used it before. This page has much going on. Here is the update. I tried to do the alert($(#hide).length); It gives the error can not get length of null. Not sure how to check to see if jquery library loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of javascript errors and actions being disabled. I was trying to make edits to a page made by another developer. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

The script is running before the DOM has loaded, so `$('#hide')` doesn't exist yet.

Wrap your function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#hide').hide();
});
```

Comment: Not the case. Passing a function to the `jQuery`/`$` function is a shortcut for `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Ahh, I wasn't aware there was a shortcut for it.